# Handling special character for restore-object in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to restore files with a file from Glacier with special character file getting NoSuchKey

Error: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the RestoreObject operation: The specified key does not exist:

```
aws --profile test s3api restore-object --restore-request '\{"Days":7,"GlacierJobParameters":{"Tier":"Bulk"}}' --bucket test-my-glacier --key "e6a712e7-0652-4bab-b94c-710a8f53190b_Ë°•Ê≠£ Submission_2022.6.2.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Is this just a one-off requirement? If so, you could do it in the console. Otherwise, you'd need to program something up to get the _actual_ Key and then use that to make the request. For example, a small Python script that lists the contents of the bucket to get the Keys, then uses the returned Key to make the restore request. That would guarantee that the Key contains the correct bytes, rather than doing it on a command-line that might be interpreting the Key differently.